# Encryption key is null

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, android-keystore

My problem is that when i try to create an RSA keyPair the private key is null and i have completely no idea why. From the log at the very bottom of my screen i get [image]

Getting public key works fine, it's just the private key that doesn't, why is that?

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);

            String message = "Message to encrypt";
            byte[] byteMessage = message.getBytes();

            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            endCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 20);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                generator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("ssdPrivateKey", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP, KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                        .setKeySize(2048).build());
            } else {
                generator.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setAlias("ssdPrivateKey")
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + "ssdPrivateKey"))
                        .setStartDate(calendar.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(endCalendar.getTime())
                        .setKeySize(2048).build()
                );
            }
            KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
            PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

            byte[] bytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
            if(bytes == null) {
                Log.d("EncryptionMessage", "Bytes == null");
            }
```

Comment: any error message that you have?

Comment: @kelalaka No, everything works, i can even encrypt message with public key and decrypt it with this private key that presumably is null

Comment: @kelalaka so it means that i can't get private key in any readable form from KeyStore?

Comment: Exactly, basic security.